# Disconnect external HD when installing El Capitan upgrade?

Tags: hard-drive

I use an external HD with Time Machine to back up data.
Should I disconnect external HD before installing/upgrading to El Capitan?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. By backing up, do you mean with Time Machine?

Comment: yes (time machine)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: No, you shouldn't have to, as long as you don't select to install to it during the upgrade process.  It shouldn't hurt to disconnect it though, if you want to.

Comment: I would recommend doing it. If something goes wrong, it's better to be safe then sorry.

Comment: Of course, always air on the side of caution (unless you like learning things the hard way).

Answer (score 1):

For full belt & braces backup protection, I always remove my Time Machine drive right before a major update & replace it with a new one.

That way, if you have major issues with the new OS - incompatible drivers with no updates yet, etc - you have a 'restore point' to return to.

I also make a clone of the boot partition & I have a full Backblaze backup of everything too.
You might consider that paranoid overkill, but I haven't lost a file since the mid 90's ;-)